# For loops and reading folder names from a directory

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have a directory with various folders that I would like to archive based on user input in a batch file. The folder [Project Backups] has various projects [PJT001, PJT002, PJT003] which may vary from time to time.
The first thing I did was to set a variable based on input from the user and use that variable in a command for 7zip to archive in a particular location. This is fine for requesting to backup up one project at a time, but what if the user wanted to backup multiple projects in one go. For this I tried to create a for loop for if the user entered multiple projects when asked [PJT001 PJT003 PJT005] but I had no luck. Please see below for what I tried.

```
set /p project= Which projects to backup? !User may enter [PJT001 PJT003 PJT005]
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%G in ("%project%") do (
    %appliction% a -t7z -mx9 -mmt "%destination%\%%G" %source%\%%G
)
```

Any suggestions on where I am failing? I'm only able to archive the first project in this scenario.

The second thing I would like help with is I would like for the user to be able to imput "ALL" and all projects in the directory be archived. For this is it possible for a batch file to read all of the folder names in a directory and store in a variable, so that I can break it down into tokens and create a for loop as before (but that works ha!) so that all projects will be archived? Any better solutions are welcomed too!

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many flavors of FOR, and you need to make sure you are using the correct one.

In your case I believe you want to use the simple FOR (not FOR /F):

```
set /p project= Which projects to backup?
for %%G in (%project%) do %appliction% a -t7z -mx9 -mmt "%destination%\%%G" "%source%\%%G"
```

If want to interpret `ALL` as all projects (folders), then FOR /D will iterate folders:

```
set /p project= Which projects to backup?
if /i "%project%" equ "ALL" (
  for /d %%G in ("%source%\*") do %appliction% a -t7z -mx9 -mmt "%destination%\%%~nxG" "%%G"
else (
  for %%G in (%project%) do %appliction% a -t7z -mx9 -mmt "%destination%\%%G" "%source%\%%G"
)
```

Comment: Hi Dbenham, I tried both or your examples but still get errors. I'm struggling to get the for loop to work when looping through a single line. I have a solution that works looping thought multiple lines of a text file, but I want everything contained within the one batch file if possible.